# How to remove # from url and work without # with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pagepiling.js

i have the pagepiling jquery for sliding pages with anchors and is working just fine, but i want to make'it to run whitout the # page from the url ex: [www.mysite.com/#aboutme](http://www.mysite.com/#aboutme) <- , on click

See the plugin here: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js

Here is what i have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse sub-menu-bar" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">                        
     <li data-menuanchor="home" class="active"> <a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li data-menuanchor="aboutme"><a href="#despremine">About me</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myAnchors = [];
$( ".navbar-nav > li" ).each(function( index ) { myAnchors.push($(this).attr("data-menuanchor")); }); 

$('.fullpage-slider').pagepiling({
    scrollingSpeed: 280,
    navigation:false,
    menu: '.fullpage-progress-bar, .navbar-nav',
    sectionSelector: '.pp-scrollable',
    anchors: myAnchors,
    afterRender: function(anchorLink, index){ 
      NavbarColor(); 
    },
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){ 
        $('.pp-scrollable .section-number').removeClass('show');
        $('.active .section-number').addClass('show');
        NavbarColor();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually one of the demos on the pagePiling.js website that dos exactly that:
https://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/examples/noAnchor.html

Basically, do not use the `anchors` property during initialisation and you should be fine to go :)